# TSQL Return all matching and unmatching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is what I have to work with.

```
Table A
-------
UnitID   NamedValue   Value
Null     TestA        11
Null     TestB        30
1        TestA        20
1        TestB        15
2        TestA        18
```

Table A contains all defined values AND default values if a UnitID has not been set.
So UnitID  1 should pull up TestA value of 20 and TestB with a value of 15.
UnitID 2 should pull up TestA value of 18 and the default value TestB value 30

Results should look like the following:

```
UnitID   NamedValues   Value
1        TestA         20
1        TestB         15
2        TestA         18
2        TestB         30
```

I didn't design the thing but I have to work with it.
Please help me with a join that will provide the results needed. I can do it with temp tables but was hoping for a simple join.

Comment: UnitID has value more than 2? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it has hundreds of rows. UnitID is a key to another table, I just simplified it for an example. I'm using SQL Server

Comment: To clarify...if I have a UnitID 3 it should pull up the defaults for TestA and TestB.  The defaults are where UnitID is null. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This query finds all combinations of UnitID and NamedValue, and fills all missing values with the default. Not the most beautiful query, but it would seem to do the job;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.UnitID, b.NamedValue
  FROM Table_A a CROSS JOIN Table_A b
  WHERE a.UnitID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT cte.UnitID, cte.NamedValue, COALESCE(c.Value, d.Value) Value
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN Table_A c ON cte.UnitID = c.UnitID AND cte.NamedValue = c.NamedValue
LEFT JOIN Table_A d ON d.UnitID IS NULL AND cte.NamedValue = d.NamedValue
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34407/1).

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed, that was fast....I guess I need to look into cross joins, I've never seen it used before. Thank you it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT a.UnitID, v.NamedValues, COALESCE(v.Value, d.Value) As Value
FROM (Select 'TestA' As Nam UNION ALL Select 'TestB') v
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (Select UnitID, NamedValues, MAX(Value) As Value 
      From TableA 
      Group By UnitID, NamedValues
     ) a
    ON v.Nam = a.NamedValues
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (Select UnitID, NamedValues, MAX(Value) As Value 
      From TableA 
      Where UnitID IS NULL
      Group By UnitID, NamedValues
     ) d
    ON v.Nam = d.NamedValues
```